# How to check for duplicate row using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, duplicates, rows

how do I check for duplicate row in a table using javascript? The following is part of my code:

```
<table id="t1"> 
 <tr>
   <td>Text A</td>
   <td>Text B</td>
   <td>Cbx A</td>

 </tr>

<% int count1 = -1;
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { %>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="text" id="textA<%=i%>"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="textB<%=i%>"></td>
     <td><select name="cbx_A<%=i%>">   
           <option value="A">Option1</option>
           <option value="B">Option2</option>
         </select> 
     </td
   </tr>
<%count1 =i;
   }%>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="check(<%=count1%>)" value="Check"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

So based on this code, I will have 3 rows of text A,textB and cbxA. With that, how do I check whether user input the same values for 2 of the rows or all three rows?
I tried using servlet but theres too much work involve. So yeah is there a way to do this using java script instead?

Thanks in advance for any possible help.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code it will check for duplication in one table column
then take all rows of table that are duplicated and put their ids in array
so you will get an array of rows id
but ur table has to have an id for each row

```
var columnNumber = 1;
var table = document.getElementById('t1');
var rowLength = table.rows.length;
var arrReocrds = new Array();
var arrCount = 0;
var listCount = 0;
var arr = new Array();
 $('#t1 td:nth-child(' + colNumber + ')').each(function () {
            var recordValue = $(this).html().trim();
            var flagFirstTime = true;
            //loop through table to check redundant of current record value
            for (var i = 1; i < rowLength; i += 1) {
                {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var recordId = //put here row.id or anything that you can put it in the list
                    var cell = row.cells[colNumber - 1];
                    var value = cell.innerText.trim();
                    if (value == recordValue) {
                        if (!arr.contains(value)) {
                            if (flagFirstTime != true) {
                                arrReocrds[arrCount] = recordId;
                                arrCount++;
                            }
                            else
                                flagFirstTime = false;
                        }
                        else
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //create list for items in column 
            //to be sure that the item that has been taken and checked never be checked again by their other redundant records
            arr[listCount] = recordValue;
            listCount++;
        });
```